# INotifyPropertyChanged, How or does this work in web apps such as MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to understand if this event works properly for web apps? I know this event is very powerful in WPF/Winforms but in regards to a webform or mvc application, i can't see how it would work properly.

My main concern regarding the two scenarios, Native vs Web, is that once the Data(Mvc Model) has been sent to the client. How does a server side event get fired and magically updates the models property value on both sides, if it does at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't work with ASP.NET MVC.

Because the client in a web app is the browser, you're limited to (mostly) Javascript based solutions. You could use jQuery's 'change' event, and then use AJAX to send data back to the server:

```
// the email input has changed
$('#email').on('change', function() {

    // send the changes to the server
    $.post('/url', { email: $('#email').val() });

});
```

Once you get comfortable with Javascript and how it works in the browser, you can use a framework like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), or [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), to handle bindings and notifications (and which would be most comparable to how WPF works).

Comment: That is exactly what i thought. I just wanted more opinions on the matter since there isn't much information regarding this event and web applications. I couldn't see how it was possible but i use the jQuery methods all the time. Thanks for helping me verify my understandings of this event. :D

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged isn't part of WPF specifically. You can use it anywhere, including in web apps; but of course, it won't automatically refresh the view...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Ah fair enough, I wasn't sure what namespace it was actually in, and I haven't seen it used much outside of WPF. I suppose in the end it's just an interface.

Comment: Couldn't you pair INotifyPropertyChanged with SignalR to broadcast changes to the client?

Comment: Yea you technically can have the interface part of the model for the View. But the event won't update anything since the data is client side and the event handler is server side. There are ways to recreate this type of event but i was just simply looking for does it work "out of the box" with web apps which the clear answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't readily use that in your web pages built using HTML and JavaScript, there are some efforts which include but not limited to Uno Platform and Ooui where the view can be bound to the viewModels and therefore be updated when a property in the VM changes.

As mention in a comment, the other alternative would be to use some sort of socket based communication where changes in the server [viewModels] can be communicated to the client by something like SignalR or WebSync.